# What does e-0 mean in Python?

Tags: python, time

I am trying to measure time it took to perform my function using time.time() module.

```
start=time.time()
print(funcV1(sample,result))
finish=time.time()
```

When I calculate time-difference, it shows me e-05 at the end.
What does it mean ?

```
>>> start
1579830996.868476
>>> finish
1579830996.8685372
>>> finish-start
6.127357482910156e-05
```

Comment: e-05 is scientific notation. it means the decimal place has been moved 5 times to the right. The result is `0.0000612735748291015`

Comment: Thank you ! This has perfectly answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to measure the elapsed time to execute a funcV1 in seconds:

```
`
import time
start=time.time()
print(funcV1(sample,result))
finish= time.time()
print("elapsed time=",finish-start)
```

`